# Editable is not working in DT package in R

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I got error `editable` from `DT` package

```
Error in if (editable) params$editable = editable : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (editable) params$editable = editable :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

```
library(DT)

DT::datatable(head(iris), editable = list(
  target = 'row', disable = list(columns = c(1, 3, 4)))
)
```

This is my R `sessionInfo()`

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib64/libblas.so.3.4.2
LAPACK: /usr/lib64/liblapack.so.3.4.2

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] DT_0.5                   readr_1.3.1              tidyr_0.8.3              tibble_2.1.1            
 [5] tidyverse_1.2.1          fs_1.2.7                 RColorBrewer_1.1-2       rvg_0.2.0               
 [9] magrittr_1.5             officer_0.3.3            esquisse_0.3.0.940       scales_1.0.0            
[13] colourpicker_1.0         shinyjqui_0.3.2          plotly_4.9.0             ggplot2_3.1.1           
[17] forcats_0.4.0            arsenal_3.0.0            waiter_0.0.1             shinydashboardPlus_0.7.0
[21] future_1.12.0            data.table_1.12.2        shinyFiles_0.7.2         stringi_1.4.3           
[25] shinyjs_1.0              shinyWidgets_0.4.8       purrr_0.3.2              rintrojs_0.2.0          
[29] shinyBS_0.61             shinyalert_1.0           shinydashboard_0.7.1     stringr_1.4.0           
[33] lubridate_1.7.4          dplyr_0.8.0.1            haven_2.1.0              shiny_1.3.1             

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] nlme_3.1-137      httr_1.4.0        tools_3.5.3       backports_1.1.4   R6_2.4.0          lazyeval_0.2.2   
 [7] colorspace_1.4-1  withr_2.1.2       tidyselect_0.2.5  compiler_3.5.3    cli_1.1.0         rvest_0.3.3      
[13] xml2_1.2.0        digest_0.6.18     rmarkdown_1.12    base64enc_0.1-3   pkgconfig_2.0.2   htmltools_0.3.6  
[19] htmlwidgets_1.3   rlang_0.3.4       readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.10   generics_0.0.2    jsonlite_1.6     
[25] crosstalk_1.0.0   zip_2.0.1         Rcpp_1.0.1        munsell_0.5.0     gdtools_0.1.8     yaml_2.2.0       
[31] plyr_1.8.4        grid_3.5.3        parallel_3.5.3    listenv_0.7.0     promises_1.0.1    crayon_1.3.4     
[37] miniUI_0.1.1.1    lattice_0.20-38   hms_0.4.2         knitr_1.22        pillar_1.3.1      uuid_0.1-2       
[43] codetools_0.2-16  glue_1.3.1        packrat_0.5.0     evaluate_0.13     modelr_0.1.4      httpuv_1.5.1     
[49] testthat_2.0.1    cellranger_1.1.0  gtable_0.3.0      assertthat_0.2.1  xfun_0.6          mime_0.6         
[55] xtable_1.8-4      broom_0.5.2       later_0.8.0       rsconnect_0.8.13  viridisLite_0.3.0 tinytex_0.12     
[61] globals_0.12.4    ellipsis_0.1.0
```

Comment: Works fine with `DT 0.16`

Comment: Yes, it works on my window with DT 0.13, but I guess it is not working for linux, and I need that function for my table.

Comment: I think the way you set the `editable` option was not allowed in DT 0.5, you have to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you, I need to do that to get that option.